# How can I maximize throughput in Docker and Akka HTTP?

Tags: docker, akka, akka-http

I am building a specific jig for performance measurement.  I have a load generator, boom (https://github.com/rakyll/boom).  With this I can generate a pretty decent amount of load.

[image]
I also have a Docker image containing nginx as a load balancer, and two Akka-HTTP based REST servers.  These do nothing except count hits (they always just return 200).

Running one of these servers stand-alone (outside the Docker) I have been able to get 1000 hits/second.  Not sure if that's good or not.  In this Docker configuration that figure drops to about 220 hits/second.  I was kinda expecting, well... 2000 hits/second or thereabouts.  Higher would even be better.  I'd be happy if I can find a way to get 3-4K hits/sec with this arrangement.

I often get an error message like this:

```
  [9549]    Get http://192.168.99.100:9090/dispatcher?reply_to=foo: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:9090: socket: too many open files
```

Tried running my Docker with --ulimit nofile=2048, but that didn't help.  My application.conf for Akka is merely:

```
akka {
    loglevel = "ERROR"
    stdout-loglevel = "ERROR"
    http.host-connection-pool.max-open-requests = 512
}
```

The server code:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
  println(":: Starting Simulator on port "+args(0))
  Http().bindAndHandle(route, java.net.InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress.getHostAddress, args(0).toInt)

  var hits = 0
  var isTiming = false
  var numSec = 1

  lazy val route =
    get {
        path("dispatcher") {
            if(isTiming) hits += 1
            complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        } ~
        path("startTiming" / IntNumber) { sec =>
            isTiming = true
            hits = 0
            numSec = sec
            val timeUnit = FiniteDuration(sec, SECONDS)
            system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeUnit){ isTiming = false }
            complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        } ~
        path("tps") {
            val tps = hits/numSec * 2
            complete(s"""${args(0)}: TPS-$tps\n""")
      }
    }
}
```

Theory of operation:  Start traffic flowing then call the /startTiming/10 endpoint (for a 10-second capture on one of the 2 servers).  After 10 seconds, call /tps a couple of times and the timing node will return approx. hits/second (x2).

Any idea how I can get more performance out of this?